# Performance comparison of using django signed cookie session over django db + cache based session?

Tags: django, session, django-sessions

Django 1.4 offers several ways to maintain [django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) :

My viewpoint on using :

i) cache only : Not preferable,  users sessions may get purged out of memcache.

ii) Db + cache (`cached_db`): Preferable , simple and secure solution.

iii) Signed cookie sessions : Preferable, no database hit .

Assuming that the session data is very small i.e. no problem in storing it in cookie. Is there any performance benefit of using signed cookie over a database + memcache driven session engine ? As for N concurrent new users, there would be order of N database hits saved. This will reduce total queries that the database server has to handle per unit time.

**UPDATE** : We found redis or aerospike as really robust and high throughput session backends for django. We are using `redis` as sessions
backend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You must be able to handle N concurrent queries (N - concurrent new
>   users).

You see the difference at a **very large scale** only. You must be pessimist (server is down, bad buckup, amazon bancrupcy ) and your database must be able to handle all users in rush hours.

- 10 000 000 users with cookie session will cost you 0$ extra, problems with iframes and mobiles
- 10 000 000 users with cache  session will cost you hundreds or less than hundred  of dollars daily, lost sessions in case of restart
- 10 000 000 users with cache_db  session will cost you thousands of dollars daily (any persistent storage able to handle 1 000 000 hits in one time, 10% of users)

I use redis backend (periodic save to disk) with the possibility of switching to a cluster of memcached services.

http://www.icis.com/blogs/icis-chemicals-confidential/files/2011/10/19/goodcheapfast.jpg

Comment: Where `SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'` session data is stored?